# RTK Query - Filtering Query Results in Another Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am developing a Todo application with Nextjs 13 with app directory, prisma, redux toolkit, shadcnui and clerk. I have two components in my app. One is TodoList, and the other is Filter. In TodoList, I retrieve all my todos using RTK Query. In the Filter component, I want to filter these todos based on whether they are completed or not. I am looking for the most efficient solution for this.

My current approach is like this:

```
'use client';

import AddTodoSheet from '@/components/AddTodoSheet';
import Filter from '@/components/Filter';
import TodoList from '@/components/TodoList';
import { Separator } from '@/components/ui/separator';
import { useGetTodosQuery } from '@/redux/features/api/apiSlice';
import { Todo } from '@prisma/client';
import React from 'react';

const TodoPage = () => {
  const { data, isLoading, isError } = useGetTodosQuery({});
  const [filter, setFilter] = React.useState(null);
  const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState(data);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let filteredTodos = [];

    if (filter === 'completed') {
      filteredTodos = data?.filter((todo: Todo) => todo.isCompleted === true);
      setTodos(filteredTodos);
    }

    if (filter === 'waiting') {
      filteredTodos = data?.filter((todo: Todo) => todo.isCompleted === false);
      setTodos(filteredTodos);
    }

    if (filter === 'all') {
      filteredTodos = data;
      setTodos(filteredTodos);
    }
  }, [filter, data]);

  return (
    <div className=''>
      <div className='flex items-center justify-between mt-2'>
        <Filter filter={filter} setFilter={setFilter} />
        <AddTodoSheet />
      </div>
      <Separator className='my-2' />
      <div className=''>{!isLoading && <TodoList data={todos || data} />}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TodoPage;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import TodoItem from './TodoItem';
import { Todo } from '@prisma/client';

const TodoList = ({ data }: { data: any }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((todo: Todo) => (
        <TodoItem key={todo.id.toString()} todo={todo} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default TodoList;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { Tabs, TabsList, TabsTrigger } from './ui/tabs';

const Filter = ({ filter, setFilter }: { filter: any; setFilter: any }) => {
  return (
    <Tabs defaultValue='all' onValueChange={(e) => setFilter(e)}>
      <TabsList>
        <TabsTrigger value='all'>All</TabsTrigger>
        <TabsTrigger value='completed'>Completed</TabsTrigger>
        <TabsTrigger value='waiting'>Waiting</TabsTrigger>
      </TabsList>
    </Tabs>
  );
};

export default Filter;
```

Is there more good solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is good enough for a todoList...

In a situation where you have large data. you might experience some performance issues with the app.

Except you load 100 out of 2000 datasets and filter that small portion on the client side.

Your Rtk query will look like this

```
    getAllTodo: build. Query({ 
        query: ({ page, pageSize, filter, sort, search }) => ({
            url:"client/alltodo",
            method: "GET",
            params: { page, pageSize, sort, search},
        }),
        providesTags: ["Todolist"]
    }),
```

and your api url will look like this https://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/client/alltodo?page=1&pageSize=20&filter=warning

This way you can paginate the data filter and sort. If the data isn't large... then you don't have to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your advice. As it is, it works as I want, I believe there is a better solution but I haven't found it yet. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a React anti-pattern to compute and store derived state in React state. The filtered result is derived from the fetched/cached `data` and the current `filter` state value. In fact, in just about all cases if you have found that you have coded a `useState`/`useEffect` pair this is a sign that you have implemented this anti-pattern and should just compute the derived value or use the `useMemo` hook if it is "expensive" or needs to be a stable reference if the component rerenders often for other reasons.

Just compute the `todos` array.

Examples:

```
const todos = data.filter(todo => {
  switch(filter) {
    case "completed":
      return todo.isCompleted;

    case "waiting":
      return !todo.isCompleted;

    default:
      return true;
  }
});
```

or more succinctly at the possible expense of readability

```js
const todos = data.filter(({ isCompleted }) => filter === "all"
  ? true
  : filter === "completed"
    ? isCompleted
    : !isCompleted
);
```

Memoized versions

```
const todos = React.useMemo(() => data.filter(todo => {
  switch(filter) {
    case "completed":
      return todo.isCompleted;

    case "waiting":
      return !todo.isCompleted;

    default:
      return true;
  }
}), [data]);
```

or more succinctly

```js
const todos = React.useMemo(() => data.filter(({ isCompleted }) => filter === "all"
  ? true
  : filter === "completed"
    ? isCompleted
    : !isCompleted
), [data]);
```

Complete component code:

```js
const TodoPage = () => {
  const { data, isLoading, isError } = useGetTodosQuery({});
  const [filter, setFilter] = React.useState("all");

  const todos = data.filter(({ isCompleted }) => filter === "all"
    ? true
    : filter === "completed"
      ? isCompleted
      : !isCompleted
  );

  return (
    <div className=''>
      <div className='flex items-center justify-between mt-2'>
        <Filter filter={filter} setFilter={setFilter} />
        <AddTodoSheet />
      </div>
      <Separator className='my-2' />
      <div className=''>
        {!isLoading && <TodoList data={todos} />}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```